Shopware AddExtension to Aggregation via Subscriber , StructEncoder::isAllowed(): Argument #2 ($property) must be of type string, int given
I'm trying to add via Subscriber on ProductListingResultEvent data to my Filter.
On ProductListingCollectFilterEvents there is a Filter added (it fetches out of over 15000 tickets the different tickettypes via aggregation) there are about 20 different types, each type of ticket,gets his own availability :
..... code before to filter 


public function addTicketTypeFilter(ProductListingCollectFilterEvent $event): void
    {
        $filters = $event->getFilters();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $filtered = false;
        $filter = new Filter(
            'TicketType',
            $filtered,
            [
                new FilterAggregation(
                    'TicketType',
                    new TermsAggregation('TicketType', 'TicketTypeName'),
                    [$aggregationFilter]
                ),
            ],
            $criteriaFilter,
            $filtered
        );
        $filters->add($filter);
   }

The Problem is we need the availability dates. I subscribed on ProductListingResultEvent , get the results  than i take the aggregations of
this is the onProductListingResult Function
 public function onProductListingResult(ProductListingResultEvent $event): void
    {
         $result = $event->getResult();
         $ticketTypeAggregation = $result->getAggregations()->get('TicketType');
         if ($ticketTypeAggregation) {
            $buckets = $ticketTypeAggregation->getBuckets();

            if (!$buckets) {
                return;
            }
            $availabilityDateMapping = array();

            foreach ($buckets as &$bucket) {
                $criteria = new Criteria();
                $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('TicketTypeName', $bucket->getKey()));
                $criteria->setLimit(1);
                $dateResult = $this->ticketRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();

                if (!$dateResult || !$dateResult->getFirstAvailabilityDate()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $date = $dateResult->getFirstAvailabilityDate();
                $formatted = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $availabilityDateMapping[] = [
                    'key' => $bucket->getKey()?? '',
                    'date' => $formatted,
                ];
            }
            $bucketResult = new BucketResult('TicketTypeName', $buckets);
            $bucketResult->addExtension('TicketAvailabilityMapping',new ArrayStruct($availabilityDateMapping));
            $result->getAggregations()->add($bucketResult);
        }
    }

My Problem is i get this Error below, when i remove the function call in the subscriber , the error is gone, so it has to be caused in the onProductListingResult Function
Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Api\StructEncoder::isAllowed(): Argument #2 ($property) must be of type string, int given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/System/SalesChannel/Api/StructEncoder.php on line 99
